# Duplicate title tags and meta descriptions in Google Webmaster Tools despite canonical tags

Tags: google-search-console, duplicate-content, canonical-url

My website name is "Global Blurb". For the last month, I have been facing an error in Google Webmaster Tools with duplicate title and meta descriptions.  See the screen shot:

[image]

I am using canonical URL.  I also disallow `replytocom?` in robot.txt, but the  problem still here.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: What is "replytocom" for?

Comment: Your site is not using canonical tags correctly.   I looked at the source code for one of your articles.  It has three rel canonical tags.  Two point to the home page `<link rel="canonical" href="http://globalblurb.com/" />` and one points to the article URL without the slash.   The two that point to the home page are extremely dangerous.   I've seen sites fall out of the index entirely because of that.   Google may be just ignoring all your canonical tags because of the problems.

Answer (score 2):

You should implement 301 redirects from the non-trailing slash version to the trailing slash version, e.g. `/somepage` to `/somepage/`

Google treats those URL variations as totally different pages, therefore reporting duplicate content.

If you 301 redirect `/somepage` to `/somepage/` then Google will "see" only the `/somepage/` version.

Comment: I need make redirect like that redirect 301 /jails-penalty-on-facebook /http://globalblurb.com/jails-penalty-on-facebook